# Playing sound in JavaFX when button is pressed, window pops up

Tags: java, javafx, audio

So I made a class for playing a sound in JavaFX when a button is pressed, a window pops up... I don't know about the quality of the code though. I don't know if I used the best way to play the sound. It's meant to be used to play small mp3 or wav files (not longer than 5 seconds) I made it so you can adjust the volume of it (i.e. an option menu where you can adjust your notification sound menu)

Here's the code:

```
public class Sound {

String file;
Media sound;
MediaPlayer player;

public Sound(String file) {
    this.file = file;
    this.sound = new Media(new File(file).toURI().toString());
    this.player = new MediaPlayer(sound);
}

public void play(){
    player.play();
}

public void stop(){
    player.stop();
}

public void setVolume(double value){
    player.setVolume(value);
}

public double getVolume(){
    return player.getVolume();
}
}


//A little GUI with a button that plays a sound and a volume slider for that sound

public class MusicPane extends Pane {


String path;
Sound sound;
public MusicPane(String path) {

    this.path = path;
    this.sound  = new Sound(path);

    //if this button is pressed, it plays the sound
    Button button = new Button("play");
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            //first stop a playing sound, then start the sound
            sound.stop();
            sound.play();
        }
    });

    //Slider to adjust the volume
    Slider slider = new Slider();
    slider.setMin(0);
    slider.setMax(1.0);
    slider.setValue(sound.getVolume());

    slider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
            sound.setVolume(slider.getValue());
        }
    });
    this.getChildren().addAll(button, slider);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get great answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally more standard to hide as many fields of your class as possible. I'd recommend making  `file`, `sound` and `player` in `Sound` as well as `path` and `sound` in `MusicPane` private.

Additionally you're not using `file` in `Sound`, so you can remove it. Furthermore your class' bodies are not indented by one level (contrary to usual conventions).

Aside from that there's not much to say about `Sound` the only thing that may be improved is using `Paths.get` instead of `new File` when you create your sound.

The `MusicPane` has a bit more to talk about. For one I don't quite understand why you're not using an fxml to specify the components. Additionally conventional wisdom suggests to use composition over inheritance. Instead of subclassing `Pane` into a `MusicPane`, you should use the Pane as a Member of the "GUI" you expose to your program.

This allows you to better share behaviour between components you create by subclassing Components instead of `Pane`.

The comments in the code aren't really useful... `// if this button is pressed, it plays the sound` can be completely removed, especially when you rename the `button` to `play`.
`//first stop a playing sound, then start the sound`  can be completely removed. It adds no information whatsoever to the code.
`//Slider to adjust the volume` becomes completely superfluous as soon as you rename `slider` to `volumeSlider`.